# Derivative of trace distance

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

If we have two time-dependent density matrices $\rho(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$.
The trace distance is
$$
D(\rho(t),\sigma(t))=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr} \vert \rho(t)-\sigma(t) \vert.
$$
Does an explicit formula for
$$\frac{d D(\rho(t),\sigma(t))}{dt}$$
exist? Only the domain where $\rho \neq \sigma$ is asked for.

Comment: What is $|A|$ for a symmetric matrix $A$?

Comment: For Hermitian $A$, $|A|=\sqrt{A}^2$. It's roughly a generalization of the absolute value for matrices.

Comment: In the case 1x1 matrices isn't there a problem with differentiability at points where $\rho (t)=\sigma (t)$?

Comment: When $\rho(t)=\sigma(t)$ that corresponds to two identical states, which is not physically worth considering. The rest of the domain is fine so I don't see a problem.

Comment: @A15234B if $\rho(t)-\sigma(t)$ is singular, the distance won't be differentiable at $t$.

Comment: @user251257 True, but the directional derivative will exist and can be written down (which OP may be interested in).

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer What would the directional derivative be in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the new matrix variables 
$$\eqalign{
 A &= \rho(t)-\sigma(t) \cr
 B &= A^HA \cr
}$$

Then the function, differential, and gradient can be written as 
$$\eqalign{
D &= \frac{1}{2}{\rm tr}(B^{1/2}) \cr
dD
 &= \frac{1}{4}B^{-1/2}:dB \,\,\,=\,\,\, \frac{1}{4}B^{-1/2}:(A^H\dot{A}+\dot{A}^HA)\,dt \cr
\frac{dD}{dt}
 &= \frac{1}{4}B^{-1/2}:(A^H\dot{A}+\dot{A}^HA) \cr
}$$
where the colon is a product notation for the trace, i.e. 
$\,\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

Comment: Which fails if $B$ isn't invertible.